# Appending user credentials to header for websocket connection request

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http-headers, websocket

The web socket server implementation has a "verify client" function with a true or false return value for if the user is allowed to connect or not.

Although I believe the intention of this function was simply for checking the origin of the request, it seems too good to pass up for authentication aswell.

Given that I am targeting Chrome as my client, is there any way I can pass some user credentials in the header of the web socket connection request? Or any other way I can use this function to avoid creating my own handshake protocol?